# Bar of pie position in Matplotlib chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm learning Matplotlib and trying to understand [this piece of code](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/bar_of_pie.html).

As part of an exercise, I need to figure out how to place the bar to the left side of the pie.

Can anyone help?

Comment: From the lines, `ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121); ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)`, the three digit numbers specify the position of each subplot, (number of rows, number of columns, position index starting from 1). So to place bar plot on the left, you can switch the last digit for those two subplots. And of course you need to make changes on the connecting lines and etc.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks for helping me learn something!